# Happening of something that is beyond of one's expectation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom or phrase or word associated with something good that is beyond of one's expectation and happens to him or her?

Comment: Please give some context. I can think of many words. Please can you provide a sample sentence and leave a blank where the word would go. Then we know whether it needs a noun or an adjective or a verb.

Comment: @chasly from UK,For example , in deals or contrat . what about idiom?

Comment: Do you want a noun, an adjective or a verb?

Comment: @chasly from UK., ambiguity of OP is corrected.

Comment: Simply **unbelievable** or **surprising**.

Comment: Why are you looking for this word / expression / idiom? Is there a particular reason? Otherwise "astonished"; "surprised"; "thrilled to bits", "over the moon"; "gobsmacked"; "a dream come true" could all fit. The question IMO is too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The word ***serendipity*** seems appropriate to your description:

> : luck that takes the form of finding valuable or pleasant things that are not looked for
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serendipity)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[Manna from heaven](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/manna+from+heaven) is an idiom meaning "something very good that you did not expect." (Cambridge Dictionary of American Idiom, cited in The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest [**'Beyond my wildest dreams'**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beyond+wildest+dreams) TFD defines it as:

> far more than you could have hoped for or imagined

*"His company has succeeded beyond his wildest dreams."*

Answer (score 0):

**Unforseen**, perhaps, although this does not make clear whether the event is *good* or *bad*.

Comment: (my answer was posted before the OP edit that clarified that a 'good' event was intended)

Answer (score 0):

**Miracle** is often used for situations such as these, although it could be construed to have religious undertones.

Comment: It's so big for it, and what about idiom?

Comment: Hi Revulai, you should consider adding a definition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> in deals or contracts

In deals, certainly, there is a perfect word for this:

**windfall**

Google gave me: *a piece of unexpected good fortune, typically one that involves receiving a large amount of money.  Example: "windfall profits"*

Answer (score 0):

> It was **more than I could have hoped for**.

Or

> I **won the lottery**/**hit the jackpot**.

How about

> I *struck oil in my backyard**.

Then there's the standard

> **exceeds expectations**

I doubt you'll find any single word that exactly fits what you want. When something like that happens to a person, they usually want to express it in more than one word. Normally, they are so happy that at least one adjective needs to be used just to emphasize how great it was. Wouldn't want to rob someone of that pleasure, would we?